# How to speed up this integration?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I try to evaluate this integral:

```
eq[k_, q_, b_, f_] = (1/Sqrt[h^2 - k^2])* Sinh[Sqrt[h^2 - k^2]*(q - b)]*(1/(h*b))*(m^2*y[b]^2 - (1/(h*b))* D[y[b], b]^2) + (1/Sqrt[h^2 - k^2])*Sinh[Sqrt[h^2 - k^2]*(q - f)]*(1/(h*b))*(m^2*y[f]^2 - (1/(h*f))* D[y[f], f]^2);
```

Where $m= h = 10^{14}$ GeV, and the initial integration limit $a= -10^{14}$ GeV.

```
  y[b_]:= b^(1/2 + Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]) + b^(1/2 - Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]); 
    
    y[f_]:= f^(1/2 + Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]) +  f^(1/2 - Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]);
```

To double integrate `eq` once with respect for `b` and once with respect for `f`, I use a symbolic integration

```
i1[k_, f_,q_]=Map[Integrate[#, {b, a, q}] &, eq[k, q, b, f] // FullSimplify // Expand]

i2[k_,q_]=Map[Integrate[#, {f, a, q}] &, i1[k,f,q] // FullSimplify // Expand]
```

Then I want to plot `i2[k,q]` in the limit where $q\to 0$, so I use:

```
i3[k_]:= Limit[i2[k,q],q \to 0]
```

The problem is that this integration takes so much time, especially `i2` it has not even been evaluated. So is there a way to speed up this integration and make its evaluation easier?

**Hint**

I'm using MA12.0. And in a previous thread

[How to make NIntegrate with large integration limit?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291983/how-to-make-nintegrate-with-large-integration-limit)

I tried `NIntegrate` but it doesn’t run with large initial integration limit $a$ and I could not take the limit of q.

**Edit**

Here are my trials to do i1 and i2 in one step based on the answer Of Ulrich Neumann and to avoid the non covergence error message:

`Map[Integrate[#, {b, a, q}, {f, a, q}, Assumptions -> {a < 0}] &, expr]`

This gives a Condtitional expression:  Re[q] $\leq$ a || a Re $\frac{1}{-a+q}) \leq -1 $ || q is not [Element] R

So I think this is the problem `a` should be ( > 0 ), so that `q` is an integer. So I try:

`Limit[Map[Integrate[#, {b, a, q}, {f, a, q}, Assumptions -> { q \[Element]  Integers && a > 0}] &, expr],q->0]`

Since I initially want to determine the integral at the  `q->0 Limit`, but this gives `Indeterminate`

Comment: What is the point of defining the same function twice? Once as `y[b_]` and then as `y[f_]`?   In your previous question you had $h=m=10^{14} GeV$ now you have $h=m=14 GeV$. Do you even know what you want to compute?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function y?

Comment: Hi @azerbajdzan. Thanks for correction, it’s  $m= h = 10^{14}$ GeV and $ a=-h= -10^{14}$ GeV. `y[b]` and `y[f]` , because the function `y` is double integratted once for `b` and once for `f`. Also in the previous question I tried `NIntegrate` but it doesn’t run with large $a$ and I can’t take the limit of `q`

Comment: @Dr. phy: The definition of a function does not care what is the name of a variable. You could just as well define it as `y[x_]` and then use it like `D[y[b], b]` or `D[y[f], f]`. No need to define it twice. $h=m=10^{14} GeV$ so then what is the actual value of `h`? `10^14*10^9` or `10^14`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan. Well! $h=10^{14}$ GeV and $m=10^{14}$ GeV

Comment: @Dr.phy Which values takes `k`?

Comment: @Dr.phy Function `y[b]` is complex for `b<0`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming  `m==h` and `a<0<q` Mathematica 12.2 states non-convergent integral:

```
m=h
y[b_] := b^(1/2 + Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]) + b^(1/2 - Sqrt[1 + m^2/h^2]);
expr = (1/Sqrt[h^2 - k^2])*Sinh[Sqrt[h^2 - k^2]*(q - b)]*(1/(h*b))*(m^2*y[b]^2 - (1/(h*b))*D[y[b], b]^2) 
+ (1/Sqrt[h^2 - k^2])*Sinh[Sqrt[h^2 - k^2]*(q - f)]*(1/(h*b))*(m^2*y[f]^2 
- (1/(h*f))*D[y[f], f]^2);  // Expand
expr[[0]] = List (* list the parts of `expr`
```

Integration

```
Map[Integrate[#, {b, a, q}, {f, a, q}, Assumptions -> {a < 0 < q}] &, expr]
```

doesn't converge, gives error message

`Integrate::idiv: Integral of (1/(4 m^2 Sqrt[-k^2+m^2]))b^(-3-2 Sqrt[2]) (9-4 Sqrt[2]-14 b^(2 Sqrt[2])+(9+4 Sqrt[2]) b^(4 Sqrt[2])-4 b^3 (1+b^(2<<1>><<5>><<1>><<1>>]))^2 m^3) (a-q) Sinh[Sqrt[-k^2+m^2] (-b+q)] does not converge on {a,q}.`

Comment: Hi@Ulrich Neumann. Thanks a lot for your reply. In the code : `m==h`, but still in the expr `m` and `h` appear independently. I thought one variable should appear `m` or `h` . So why `m==h` ?

Comment: Sorry , my fault , it must be `m=h`

Comment: Hello @Ulrich Neumann. Please may you see the edit of the question.  I tried to vary the `Assumptions ` to get a definite  integral. Also I try to get the `Limit` of the integral at ` q\to0` but MA gives `indeterminate`.

Comment: @Dr.phy I think these assumptions are all included in my answer, especially  `Limit q->0`